# Nested Nav goes out of its parent anchor element

Tags: html, nav

I am trying to implement a sub-menu using nested listless Nav, as shown in the code below.

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <a href="#">A1</a>
  <a href="#">A2
    <nav id="sub-nav">
      <a href="#">A2.1</a>
    </nav>
  </a>
  <a href="#">A3</a>
</nav>
```

But, the problem is that "sub-nav" goes out of the anchor tag to become its sibling instead of being its child, as shown in the snippet below (Copied from Chrome Inspect Window). Besides, an empty anchor node is added out of no where under the "sub-nav"

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">A1</a>
  <a href="#">A2</a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a>2.1</a>
  </nav>

  <a href="#">A3</a>
</nav
```

I tried changing "sub-nav" display to inline, but nothing changed. I found this behavior on both Chrome & FireFox. So, do you know what would be the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: Originally, I am adding an onclick handler to the anchor to show/hide the "sub-nav", so it should appear under that anchor. It works as it should be, but with this extra anchor showing. Also, when I am trying to get the anchors children using JS, the "sub-nav" is not there..

Comment: I'm sorry, this is really vague.  Please add image(s) so we can see what the final output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place an anchor tag inside an anchor tag, even if the nested anchor is contained by an `<nav>` element.

Convention would be to use `<ul>` tags to nest navigational elements (a list of links).

Chrome is just being nice and trying to fix the invalid markup.

Comment: You are correct @superUntitled. I got distracted by the Nav element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">A1</a></li>
    <li>A2
        <ul id="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">A2.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is coming from putting a  element inside of an  element.